# not able to update same page as per dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have to update same page with new image as per users choice

views.py

```
def search_form(request,xid):
print xid
if request.GET.get('search'):
    search = request.GET.get('search')
    print "in search"
    print search
    xid = search
    return render(request,'search_form.html',{'xid':xid})    
else:
    return render(request,'search_form.html',{'xid':xid})    

def temp(request,xid):    
    """ forming chart image using matplotlib"""
```

> urls.py

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^temp/(?P<xid>\d{4})/$', views.temp, name='temp'),
  url(r'^search_form/(?P<xid>\d{4})/$', views.search_form, name='search_form'),)
```

> template search_form.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        <select name=search>
        <option value="1234">1234</option>
        <option value="7426">7426</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        <img src='/temp/{{ xid }}'>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My issue is when i select option from dropdown it is looking for url like 
GET 
below(here i am viewing image for 1234) and trying to uget new one after selecting 7426 from dropdown but url formed like below and page is not updated as below url formed.

> /search_form/1234/?search=7426

but i need it should form something like

```
/search_form/7426
```

Is i am doing anything wrong here what is best way to deal with it or should i change the url pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form` has no `action` attribute, so the GET will be directed to the current url, that is to say `/search_form/1234/`. If you want to direct it to another url, add an `action` attribute. For instance

```
 <form method="get" action="/search_form/">
```

This will yield the url `/search_form/?search=7426` if `7426` is selected. You also need to modify the view:

```
def search_form(request, xid=None):
    # Same here
```

If you don't want to hardcode `/search_form/`, you can add another named url in your patterns, like

```
url(r'^search_form/$', views.search_form, name='base_search_form')
```

And

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'base_search_form' %}">
```

Comment: updated geting this /search_form/?search=7426 url so giving error   search_form() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) .should i change the url pattern for search_form?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the view. Answer updated. Also if you want to keep only one url, you need to use some javascript as @Yossi suggested.

Comment: thannks for updating.updated the code but again geting below message at console [21/May/2014 20:29:31] "GET /search_form/?search=7426 HTTP/1.1" 200 448 and page got hanged as i think url pattern is not matching.

Comment: If you received GET /search_form/?search=7426 HTTP/1.1" 200, the http status code 200 means that everything went fine, so the url pattern worked. What happened after you submit? Did the console displayed the print xid then the print "in search" and print search?

Comment: console message is like below  [21/May/2014 20:45:07] "GET /temp/1234/ HTTP/1.1" 200 75029 
None
in search
7426
[21/May/2014 20:45:11] "GET /search_form/?search=7426 HTTP/1.1" 500 95868

Comment: so yes its displayed "insearch" xid value 7426 is also got retrived

Comment: I don't see what it does not work. Does the error message that gives the error 500 is still " giving error search_form() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"? If you modify search_form, that should not happen. Based on last comment, the "in search" is printed in the view "temp", not in "search_form"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54137/discussion-between-sagar-and-sebastien-deprez).

Comment: I found weired bahaviour here it worked in mozila when i first see evrey image using  /temp/1234 url after that it works when call from search_form function.I think browser catche is playing role here.still not the perfect solution but somehow its worked.I think need to try it using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You must use javascript to update form's url according to user's selection.